# How to make a onclick redirect that only redirects if you're signed in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've made a sign up sign in page using firebase but I have a button to a second page that I only want people who are signed in to access. I want it so if you aren't signed in it sends an alert but if you are it just redirects you. At the moment the alert comes up whether you're signed in or not so it's not recognising the user. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is my first time using firebase.

I have a button in my html with an onclick function and this is the function it is calling.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

function homepage() {
    if(user) {
        window.location = '/homepage.html';
    } else {
        alert("Please Sign In");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `var user = ...` inside the `homepage()` function? I suspect the variable gets assigned when this script is initially loaded, but when the function is called (at a time when the user might have subsequently authenticated), the `user` variable is not assigned the updated value.

Comment: oh for gods sake it would be that simple wouldn't it haha. Thanks man!

Comment: XD glad it sorted you out! I'll add the comment as an answer to make it easier for anyone that stumbles in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `var user = ...` inside the `homepage()` function? I suspect the variable gets assigned when this script is initially loaded, but when the function is called (at a time when the user might have subsequently authenticated), the `user` variable is not assigned the updated value.